Optimization problem algorithm: splitting elements that are preferred to be together
I can't come up with an algorithm for my problem.
I have a list of lists, let's say 10 values in total. List size is: 10 >= size >= 1
Each list represents the values that are preferred to keep together if possible. I need to split them between a specific number of chunks (numberOfChunks), so that the size of each chunk is close to the preferred size (preferredChunkSize = total elements / numberOfChunks) and the real chunk size should follow the condition: preferredChunkSize + maxDeviation >= real chunk size >= preferredChunkSize - maxDeviation.
Function declaration:
function split(buckets: list<list>, numberOfChunks, maxDeviation)

Example 0
buckets = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
chunks = split(buckets, 5, 0)
// acceptable options (max deviation equals 0, so we don't allow the size to be more or less than 2
// [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]

Example 1
buckets = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
chunks = split(buckets, 5, 1)
// acceptable options
// [[1,2,3],[4],[5],[6,7,8],[9,10]]

Example 2
buckets = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8], [9], [10]]
chunks = split(buckets, 2, 1)
// acceptable options
// [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]

Example 3
buckets = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8], [9], [10]]
chunks = split(buckets, 3, 1)
// acceptable options
// [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,10]]

Any help will be appreciated! Maybe this or a similar problem already exists? Can anyone name it?

This needs a bit more formalism before it can be solved.
The problem statement says that chunk sizes must be in the given ranges.
However, with only that hard constraint, a solution would be to just split into chunks as evenly as possible, disregarding the initial chunks entirely.
There is also a soft constraint in the following form: the values in the initial lists are preferred to be kept together if possible. This has to be quantified somehow. For example, we can introduce a penalty function, and add 1 unit of penalty for every pair of elements which were in the same list but aren't in the answer. Or penalize every pair of consecutive such elements.

When we have such formal function, we can optimize it, that is, try to find an answer with the minimum total penalty.
This looks like it can be done, for example, by dynamic programming.
Consider states of the following form:

we already built k chunks
we already used a total of e elements

The task is to minimize the penalty function f (k, e).
Obviously, the base case is f (0, 0) = 0.
Now, loop over the number of elements for the next chunk, n.
We go from state (k, e) to state (k + 1, e + n).
The penalty for the added chunk can be calculated on-the-fly, since we know, for each of the n elements taken, which list it originates from, how many of its neighbors will be in the same chunk, and how many will go to other chunks.
The optimal value will be f (total chunks, total elements).
Perhaps with this value we will also store the way to obtain such value, which will then give the answer immediately.
